# "3 тревог" в описании иконки модератора

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора, доступность

```
<a href="/admin/dashboard" class="-link _text-only" aria-label="3 тревог" title="3 сообщения, отмеченных тревогой для привлечения внимания модераторов">
                <span class="indicator-badge _regular">3</span>
            </a>
```

> aria-label="3 тревог"

Должно быть "3 тревоги".

Comment: В традусёре есть такие строки, но там правильный перевод. Возможно в оригинале не так строка юзается.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, `aria-label="2 тревог"`.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, `aria-label="1 сообщение, помеченное тревогой"` - вообще другой текст о_О

Comment: Появилося после апдейта.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ага, вижу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ок, вижу. Строка https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12474

Кто-то перепутал с другой строкой, видимо, и вписал перевод для строки `$__count$ flags`. Поправил на:

> $__count$ сообщения, помеченных тревогой